# Feature request: &page=last link for paginated results

Tags: feature-request, search, user-experience

[My Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) contains a link to the lowest-voted answers of mine; but it currently requires updating every <del>20</del> *30* answers or so because I had to hard-code the index of the last page of results (currently at 84).

Since the UI already knows that there are 84 pages (there is already a link to the last page in the footer), could you please also make it recognize a symbolic link name like "last" (or perhaps "-1"?) to go to the highest-numbered page in the result set?  Then I would not have to update the link periodically.

Comment: I suppose supporting `&order=asc` would work just as well as `&page=last` and perhaps generalize somewhat better.